# How to fire two diffrent code with same floatingactionbutton in tabview flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working with a flutter project in which I need to fire two different code with the same floating action button:

here is my tab view:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: TabBar(indicator: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black12, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
      ),
        tabs: [
          Tab(text: 'Drivers'),
          Tab(text:'Cars')
        ],
        labelColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
```

and my tab bar view:

```
body: TabBarView(
        children:[
          SingleChildScrollView(...),
          Center(child: Text('add car screen'))
        ]
    ),
```

and a floating button:

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // Add your onPressed code here!
      },
```

and here is the image

[image: which shows the design]

What I want is whenever Driver tab is selected, and then I press the floating action button it must print "driver tab selected" and whenever I switch tab to car tab, and then I press the button it prints "car tab is selected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your Scaffold inside of a Builder and you can then retrieve the tab index with DefaultTabController.of(context).index

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  

  
void main() => runApp(MyApp());  
  
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return MaterialApp(  
      home: DefaultTabController(  
        length: 2,  
        child:  Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(  
          appBar: AppBar(  
            title: Text('Flutter Tabs Demo'),  
            bottom: TabBar(  
              tabs: [  
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.contacts), text: "Drivers"),  
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt), text: "Cars")  
              ],  
            ),  
          ),  
           floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if(DefaultTabController.of(context)!.index==1)
        {
          print("drivers");
        }
        else
          print("cars");
         print(
                'Current Index: ${DefaultTabController.of(context)!.index}');
      },),
          body: TabBarView(  
            children: [  
              Center(child:Text("Driver")) ,
              Center(child:Text("Cars")) ,
            ],  
          ),  
        );
        }  
      ),  
    )
    );  
  }  
}
```

Or you can also use onTap method in TabBar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  

  
void main() => runApp(MyApp());  
  
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  
  int currentScreen=0;
  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return MaterialApp(  
      home: DefaultTabController(  
        length: 2,  
        child: Scaffold(  
          appBar: AppBar(  
            title: Text('Flutter Tabs Demo'),  
            bottom: TabBar(  
              onTap:(index){
                currentScreen=index;
              },
              tabs: [  
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.contacts), text: "Drivers"),  
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt), text: "Cars")  
              ],  
            ),  
          ),  
           floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if(currentScreen==0)
        {
          print("drivers");
        }
        else
          print("cars");
      },),
          body: TabBarView(  
            children: [  
              Center(child:Text("Driver")) ,
              Center(child:Text("Cars")) ,
            ],  
          ),  
        )
   ) );  
  }  
}
```

Comment: literally Excellent

Answer (score 0):

try to add DefaultTabController, [reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html):

```
int _currentIndex = 0;

        tabController.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = tabController.index;
          });
        });


 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if(_currentIndex == 0) print('');
        else print('');
      },
```